# How to filter a LinkedList with enums

Tags: java, linked-list

how can i filter my items that my "StorageManager" has in his LinkedList called "items"list with the help of enums?
Items that are affected by this filter need to get copied into a new LinkedList. Ive managed to add items into the storage managers List with buyNewItem() but need help with the second task.

If i forgot to add some important informations please let me know.

Edit : The ONLY imports that re allowed are

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

Edit 2 : I forgot the Item Class so here it is

public abstract class Item {

```
private double price;
private int ID;
private LinkedList<Allergen> allergenes;


public Item(double price,int ID) {
    super();
    this.price = price;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.allergenes = new LinkedList<Allergen>();
    
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
public LinkedList<Allergen> getAllergenes() {
    return allergenes;
}
public void setAllergenes(LinkedList<Allergen> allergenes) {
    this.allergenes = allergenes;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance! :)

```
public class StorageManager extends Employee {
    private LinkedList<Item>items;
        
    
    public LinkedList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(LinkedList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    
    public boolean buyNewItem(Item item) {
        boolean IstDA = false;
        for ( Item item1 : items) {
            if(item1.equals(item)) {
                this.items.add(item);
                IstDA = true;
                break;
            }
        }if(IstDA == false) {
            System.out.println("Ist bereits im Warenkorb");
        }
    }
        
        
    
    
    public static LinkedList<Allergen> filterStorage(filter Allergen){
        if (this.items.contain(Allergen)){
```

my enums list:

```
NUTS,PEANUTS,SOYBEANS,GLUTEN,FISH,MILK,EGGS;
```

Comment: You can use Java streams and [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-). Also, add the `Item` class to your question.

Comment: Thank you i've added it

Comment: Shouldn't `filterStorage()` return a `LinkedList<Item>`?

Comment: @user17543363 I tried to edit your code blocks, but someone else was already doing that. Could you next time add: `\`\`\`java` on the line above your code and three more `\`\`\`` on the end so it formats right for everyone :) thanks!

Comment: Sorry im pretty new to StackOverFlow i will try my best next time @NLxDoDge

Comment: yes @JohnnyMopp i made a mistake there thank you for telling me.

Comment: You can try your best *this* time. Just click the *Edit* link to fix the formatting in your code in this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't use streams, so a simple `for` loop works. The signature of the `filterStorage` looks wrong so I have modified it.

```
public LinkedList<Item> filterStorage(Allergen filter)
{
    LinkedList<Item> newList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Item item1 : items) {
        if (item1.getAllergenes().contains(filter)) {
            newList.add(item1);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```